# In Asp.net Core , Dependency Injection,How to do scope obj in a Singleton Object

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, singleton

I've got the following class definitions:

```
public class A {
    private readonly B _b;
    public A (B b){ _b = b; }
}

public class B {
    private readonly  C _c;
    public B (C c) { _c = c; }
}

public class C {
    public string IP;
}
```

And the following registrations:

```
services.AddSingleton<A>();
services.AddSingleton<B>();
services.AddScoped<C>(a => {
    var accessor = a.GetService<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor>();
    var header = accessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers;
    return new C { IP = header["X_FORWARDED_FOR"] };
});
```

the C.IP is same,

I want to it change for every client User,and A B is singleton.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to solve this, but the most elegant is the following. You just change `C` to:

```
public class C {
    private IHttpContextAccessor _accessor;
    public C(IHttpContextAccessor accessor) { _accessor = accessor; }

    public string IP => accessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers["X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
}
```

`IHttpContextAccessor` is a singleton in ASP.NET Core and calling its `HttpContext` property will always return the `HttpContext` for the current request. This allows `C` to become stateless and singleton.

This allows you to simplify the registrations to the following:

```
services.AddSingleton<A>();
services.AddSingleton<B>();
services.AddSingleton<C>();
```

This might cause problems to you in case `C` is defined in an assembly that doesn't depend on ASP.NET (such as a business layer).

This problem can be solved elegantly by introducing an abstraction `IC` for `C` and let `B` depend on `IC` instead:

```
public interface IC { }

public class B {
    private readonly  IC _c;
    public B (IC c) { _c = c; }
}
```

This way we can place `IC` in a base layer of the application (so it is accessible for `B`) and move the `C` implementation up to the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/) of the application where it is okay to depend on `IHttpContextAccessor`.

```
public class C : IC {
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _accessor;
    public C(IHttpContextAccessor accessor) { _accessor = accessor; }

    public string IP => accessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers["X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
}
```

For this to work, you need to change the registration for `C` to:

```
services.AddSingleton<IC, C>();
```

Comment: and now I have a new question:
public class A {
    private readonly B _b;
    public A (B b){ _b = b; }
}

public class B {
    private readonly  A _a;
    public B (A a) { _a = a; }
}
services.AddSingleton<A>();
services.AddSingleton<B>();

this scene  it faild, What should I do?

Comment: @amazing you should post a new question with the appropriate details (and real class names). You have a cyclic dependency and which is caused by an error in tour design: typically caused by a Single Responsibility violation.